# Extract server name and path from redirection using regex in JMeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I want to create a JMeter test case that is as generic as possible. It goes through a couple of redirections and I only want to define the starting point. The [Servername or IP:] and [Path] I want to be extracted from the response. I think this can be done using the Regular Expression Extractor.

In the second response I am getting Location Info which looks like this example:

```
Location: https://some-example.company.io/some-service/v1/signin/12345-xxx-yyyy-zzzz-loremipsum@apps_xy-something_com?relayState=121134432453525233113313
```

To further use it, I need to extract:

```
serverName: some-example.company.io

path: /some-service/v1/signin/12345-xxx-yyyy-zzzz-loremipsum@apps_xy-something_com
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the regex `https://([^/]+)([^?]*)`, the serverName will be in group 1 and the path in group 2.

It reads "discard `https://`, then capture until the first `/`, then capture until the first `?`"

Be aware that it does not check if the string looks like a regular URL (e.g "is there a top-level domain in the address", or "are there 4 groups of number" in case of IPV4)